# How can I do custom fields matching with data source in Microsoft Word 2013?

Tags: microsoft-word-2013

I have a MS Word 2013 document that uses data from an Excel 2013 file as a source. I need to be able to match a custom field in Word to a specific column in Excel sheet. How can I do this? I know that with mail merge this can be done. My purpose is to have ready made custom fields in Word before doing the mail merge so that I can use the match field feature in mail merge.

The mail merge has common predefined fields already created for use, but I need to create my own since they are specific to the data I have in Excel file.

Comment: How do you "know it can be done"? If you have an example, you should be able to work out how it was done. But as far as I can tell, you want to use the "Address" field names and field matching rather than the "Database" field names, but you want to be able to create your own "Address" field names. Is that correct? The problem is that the names of the Address fields are fixed (at least in a particular language version of Word). I do not believe there is any way to create your own "Address" field names.

Answer (score 0):

(Not sure whether that is what you want but) you can simply create a "link" from your MS Word document to the MS EXcel document using OLE (object linking and embedding). Microsoft Word inserts this field when you copy information from another application and use the Paste Special command (Edit menu) to paste it into a Word document.

Copy the cell in Excel that you want to reference, then in Word, in the location where you want the link to be, you will 'Paste Special' > 'Link & Merge Formatting'

Comment: Word document will be used to produce more than 30 documents from the excel sheet, so that is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you are looking for then?